# Writing $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j=1}^n \sigma_i\sigma_j^T$ as matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-equations

Let $\sigma$ be an $n\times n$-matrix and denote by $\sigma_i$ its $i$-th column.  How can we write the expression

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \sigma_i\sigma_j^T$$

as a matrix multiplication using $\sigma$?

Comment: So the result should be an n by n matrix, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, the answer is $\sigma\sigma^t$.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I thought.  Also I had a small question about that, if I had $\sigma\sigma^t=A$ how could I solve for sigma?

Comment: @CSA Google Cholesky decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is the matrix for which $A_{ki}= (\sigma_i)_k$, then
$$M_{kl} = \sum_{ij} (\sigma_i)_k (\sigma_j)_\ell = \sum_{ij} A_{ki}1_i A_{\ell j} 1_j  \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ \ M= (A e)(e^T A^T)=(\sigma^T e) (e^T \sigma)=v v^T$$  where $v=Av=\sigma^T e$. The last emphasize that the result is a symmetric n by n matrix of rank 1.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it a bit fast. Good way of writing. I have edited.

Comment: One may also write the last expression as $M=(e^T \sigma)^T (e^T\sigma)$. Hence $M$ is the outer product of $e^T\sigma$ with itself (i.e. the outer square of $e^T \sigma$).

Comment: I have bought that as well ;-) except in transpose form,..

Answer (score 1):

Use $e^t \sigma \sigma^t e$ where $e$ is a column vector with all entries $1$. This will give you the sum of the entries of the matrix $\sigma\sigma^t$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are given a matrix $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. Let $\mathrm a_k$ be the $k$-th column of $\mathrm A$. Hence,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm a_i \mathrm a_j^T = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm a_i \right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm a_j \right)^T = (\mathrm A 1_n) (\mathrm A 1_n)^T = \color{blue}{ \mathrm A 1_n 1_n^T \mathrm A^T }$$